# Convert the symbol :comma to ','

Tags: ruby, ruby-2.0

Is there a DRYer way to convert a symbol named `:comma` to an actual comma (`,`)?

Current approach:

```
> delimiters = {:comma =>",", :semicolon=>";"}
=> {:comma=>",", :semicolon=>";"}

> chosen = :comma

> delimiters[chosen]
=> ","
```

Ideal:

```
> x = :comma
=> :comma

> x.from_sym # not valid, obviously
=> ","
```

Comment: Shorter than `delimiters[chosen]`? Not without something horrible and hackish. You're really just asking for a shorter way of accessing an item in a hash than `hash[key]`, which doesn't exist, and really, isn't desirable. You could wrap it up in a method and write `delimiter_to_s(:comma) => ','` but really, making this any shorter isn't desirable, and it's about as DRY as it's going to get.

Comment: except of course how you have done it, using an hash (or Map as it is referred to in some languages)

Comment: if any of these answers answered you question, please mark them as correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. A symbol is equal to its string representation, but there are no other hidden meanings or transformations. This is exactly like `'2' != 2 != :'2'`, despite in this case you can apply some casting using `to_i`.

You could actually use the symbol representation of a comma, but I'm not sure it makes the code more readable.

```
2.0.0-p353 :011 > var = :','
 => :"," 
2.0.0-p353 :012 > var.class
 => Symbol 
2.0.0-p353 :013 > var.to_s
 => ","
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do this, but I wouldn't recommend it. The solution is to monkey-patch the Symbol class to give you the functionality you want. **THIS IS NOT A GOOD IDEA**

```
class Symbol
  DELIMITERS = {comma: ",", semicolon: ";"}

  def from_sym
    DELIMITERS[self]
  end
end

irb(main):015:0> chos = :comma
=> :comma
irb(main):016:0> chos.from_sym
=> ","
```

Comment: Monkey-patching a standard library for such trivial implementation, with the high risk of conflicts with other libraries, it's never a good idea.

Comment: As I said in my post in all caps. But he asked if it was possible and how, and I gave him the answer along with a warning.